# how to convert arabic content to unicode format in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have arabic content that I need to convert to unicode in `node.js`. For example `دبي`, this text should convert to `\u062f\u0628\u064a`.

What must I do to achieve this within `node.js`? Are there any packages which might help?

Comment: Improved legibility and removed some extraneous text

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.. Thank you Sippy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this module - https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsesc

```
jsesc('دبي')
'\\u062F\\u0628\\u064A'
```

This might help you too https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/1243213

Comment: Thank you VinayR.. it is working fine. This is what i am exactly looking